# How to deploy Meteor app on Linux Production Environment?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, web-deployment, pm2

I have simple meteor js app and I want to deploy it on own server.How can I do it. I tried using https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up-legacy, but I am  getting some errors which are below:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-96-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "mup"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! mup@1.3.3 postinstall: `opencollective postinstall`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mup@1.3.3 postinstall script 'opencollective postinstall'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mup package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     opencollective postinstall
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs mup
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mup
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ambu/mymeteorprojects/dummy/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

As I am new to these I don't have any knowledge about that these errors mean.

Comment: You using ubuntu or centos for remote server?

Comment: I am ubuntu @Ankur Soni .

Comment: It will make not much difference. you will use commands like `apt get install`, whereas I used `yum install`...syntax is different but approach is same. Read my answer with cool mind as it is huge, don't panic, it is easy. Follow step by step and you will see your website live :) Infact ubuntu is very easy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have below stuff available with you to install Meteor app on remote server without using `mup` package.

1. `NODE JS 4.8.4` installed.
2. `MONGO DB 3.2/3.4` installed.
3. `NGINX/APACHE` installed and running.
4. `PM2` installed.

I am using CentOS 7 for installation of Meteor 1.5.0

**Step 1:**

To create Production Specific deployable tarball, run below command.

```
meteor build --server-only .
```

> **Note**: This will create a `project_name.tar.gz` file inside your project folder. This is a tar file that is build, minified, compressed for production use, also it is not at all user friendly to read code so not easy to hack the meteor code.

**Step 2:**

You need to install specific version of node js which is compatible with your meteor version [In my case Meteor 1.5 with Node 4.8.4]

To know the process of installing node js [CLICK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46397189/3296607)

**Step 3:**

You now need mongo db on your server,

1. Run Command `sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo`

Paste following into that file

```
[mongodb-org-3.2]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.2.asc
```

Run Command sequentially as below;

2. `yum repolist`
3. `sudo yum install mongodb-org`
4. `service mongod start / service mongod stop`
5. `mongo`

> Make sure you create `database_name`,`user`,`password`.

Now export variable for shell using below commands.

6. `export MONGO_URL="mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/domain_name"`
7. `export ROOT_URL="http://localhost/"`
8. `export PORT=3000`

**Step 4:**

Now since Node and npm are installed, you can easily install `pm2` using command `npm install pm2 -g`

**Step 5:**

Copy the `project_name.tar.gz` to your server location, run command `tar -xzf 
 project_name.tar.gz` .

A `bundle` directory is created for you. Go to `bundle/programs/server` and execute command `npm install --production`. come back to `bundle/` directory and run pm2 using command `pm2 start -name "UID" main.js`. This will show you something like below;

```
[root@server ~]# cd /home/xyz/public_html/bundle/
[root@server bundle]# pm2 start --name "UID" main.js
[PM2] Starting /home/xyz/public_html/bundle/main.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
┌──────┬──────┬────────┬───┬─────┬──────────┐
│ Name │ mode │ status │ ↺ │ cpu │ memory   │
├──────┼──────┼────────┼───┼─────┼──────────┤
│ UID  │ fork │ online │ 0 │ 0%  │ 4.0 KB   │
└──────┴──────┴────────┴───┴─────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

You can confirm if your website is up or not using command `pm2 show 0` because 0 is the index of process running.

You can anytime shutdown the site using command `pm2 delete 0` or `pm2 delete all` to shut down all process handled by pm2.

In case you want to monitor the performance of the website, you can run command `pm2 monit`.

> **Note**: `pm2 start ...` command will run only inside `bundle/` folder as it looks for `main.js` file.

That's it!!! application is live on `https://<hostip or name>:3000` I struggled a lot to achieve all above stuff and make website live on remote server.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this detailed and working process description!

Answer (score 1):

Before you can start using mup that does everything for you, it's best you understand how one would normally deploy an app to production.

### **A bare-bone walk through is as below:**

Let us assume you're app is called `todos` and it's present in `/home/meteor-doge/todos`

**Get into that directory:**

`cd /home/meteor-doge/todos/`

**Build the deployable app:**

`meteor build ../ --directory`

**In the parent dir, you will now find a bundle dir:**

`cd ../
ls -ltr --> bundle`

**Do npm installs if applicable:**

`cd bundle/program/server && npm install`

**Copy the bundle directory to your production host.**

`cp -R bundle /where/ever/necessary/`

**In the production host, set the required environment variables:**

`export MONGO_URL=mongodb://hostIP:port/dbName
export ROOT_URL=https://localhost
export PORT=3000`

**Start the app:**

`/usr/bin/node /home/prod-server/path/to/bundle/main.js`

If all goes well, your app will be running in your production server and is reachable using: `http://<prod-ip>:3000`